# How to get rid of repeatable logic in the code?

Tags: c#

I have two methods:

```
static public void ReadProfiles( string path, ViewModelCollection<ProfileData> list )
{                                                                                    
    var jsonText = File.ReadAllText( path );                                         
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( jsonText ) ) return;                                  
    var profile = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ProfileData>>( jsonText );         
    if ( profile is null ) return;                                                   
    foreach ( var profileData in profile )                                           
    {                                                                                
        list.Add( new ProfileData                                                    
        {                                                                            
            Id = profileData.Id,                                                     
            Port = profileData.Port,                                                 
            Host = profileData.Host,                                                 
            Password = profileData.Password                                          
        } );                                                                         
    }                                                                                
}                                                                                    
static public void ReadTopics( string path, ViewModelCollection<PayloadData> list )  
{                                                                                    
    var jsonText = File.ReadAllText( path );                                         
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( jsonText ) ) return;                                  
    var payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<PayloadData>>( jsonText );         
    if ( payload is null ) return;                                                   
    foreach ( var payloadData in payload )                                           
    {                                                                                
        list.Add( new PayloadData                                                    
        {                                                                            
            Id = payloadData.Id,                                                     
            Title = payloadData.Title,                                               
            Topic = payloadData.Topic,                                               
            Payload = payloadData.Payload                                            
        } );                                                                         
    }                                                                                
}
```

The problem, I think, is immediately visible - ProfileData simply changes to PayloadData, the data for filling classes, respectively, change. Question: how to avoid this?

I'd like to see something like this:

```
static public void Read<T>( string path, ViewModelCollection<T> list ) where T : class, new()
{                                                                                  
    var jsonText = File.ReadAllText( path );                                       
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( jsonText ) ) return;                                
    var payload = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>( jsonText );       
    if ( payload is null ) return;                                                 
    foreach ( var payloadData in payload )                                         
    {                                                                              
        list.Add( new T
        {                                                                          
            // there is something to fill in                                          
        } );                                                                       
    }                                                                              
}
```

I understand that it is impossible to fill in T, because we do not specify the class, so the fields are generally unknown. But maybe there are some alternatives? I don't want to duplicate the code at all

Comment: The code isn't repetitive, it's verbose. The important part is different in both methods - different classes, different properties. You can clean up the code a bit, but in the end you are mapping unrelated classes

Comment: Deserializing a file to a specific type can be extracted to a generic two-line function. Instead of appending items to an existing list, *return* the new items and then use `AddRange()`

Comment: You can deserialize the file with `List<T> Read<T>(string path)=>{ var text=File.ReadAllText(); return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(text);}`. If `ViewModelCollection` behaves like a List, just use `list.AddRange(items);`. That's three lines. There's almost no reason to make an extra method for this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it looks so good, thanks!